# Server for android game

Tags: android, python

I am going to create game for android, this game has multiplayer mode, so it should send ang get some data from server.

Lets assume that 5 players are playing this game.
Each player on his turn sends a word to server, server checks if this word is correct and then server sends this word to other players.

Also server has some kind of timer, and when times goes out it sends to all player then time is up.

Very simple.

Now what is my problem. I have never done web programming and I don't know how to implement server side. Google gived me several options:

- Http server
- Sockets server

What should I use? One of this options or something else?
Also what frameworks/libraries can be helpful in implimentation? I'd prefer python (like CherryPy if http server is good for my purpouses), but also I can do it on java or c++. Or on php (but I don't want to use it)

**Update**

After thinking for a while I used python tcp socket server. It seems to be most lightweighted solution for my needs. Also it is easy to interact with it from Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [Twisted Python](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) and roll your own simple protocol using persistent connections.

Alternatively, use a normal HTTP(s) server like Apache or nginx and [WSGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) to tie in your python backend logic.  To make it appear as if you have a persistent connection (used to notify everyone of the "word" that was submitted or the expiration of a timer), you'll need to use something like [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Comment: If you're going to do it over http, you're going to need to handle the push portion of your application.  If you build your own protocol that maintains open connections to each player after they initially connect, you'll be able to notify them directly.  If you do it via http, you'll need to use something like AJAX to provide the illusion that the connection stays open.  Also, if you're going to do HTTP/AJAX, it's probably simpler to use Apache or nginx and wsgi for the python app behind it.

Comment: And does android have tools to develop communication with my own protocol?

Comment: I believe Twisted is available in ASE (http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) so you could write your client in Python as well. If you write the client side in Python, you would abstract out your protocol logic (basically, how to serialize and deserialize) and use that code on both the server and the client.  If you do it via http/ajax, I'd expect that stuff to be available in a standard android install.  With that said, my answer was directed at the server side of things and I don't have much experience with android development work.

Comment: Well, seems that I should try to make simple application with twisted and ASE, if I won't find something easier. And http/ajax solution looks like something very heave, but maybe I am wrong

Comment: The biggest disadvantage in the twisted/ASE solution on the client side is that it will be significantly harder for end-users to install (ASE requires side-loading or rooting) so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using parse?

https://parse.com/

Another good option I like is NodeJS, however you will get alot of the same benefits such as Asynchronous Concurrency from Tornado (Python)

Comment: As I understand parse is for storing and retriving data, but I can't implement game logic using it. I need to check if words are correct on server side. About NodeJS I have to look I little bit more, maybe it can help me